# Selenium Java ChromeDriver - How to disable attached sites

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When loading a web page, it sometimes keep hanging on loading sites like "google analytics", "gstatic.com", etc.

It sometimes hangs forever.

Is there a way to disable this behavior?

Comment: There is a way to restrict this behavior but on the contrary you would be never sure if the HTML DOM have completely loaded or not for you to continue working with the WebElements present on that Webpage :)

Comment: @Dev So, maybe I should give it a try... Can you please let me know how?

Comment: Did you check out my Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with Selenium 3.4.0 along with the latest chromedriver 2.29 & latest Google Chrome 58.0 to restrict the loading of the sites you can take help of `pageLoadStrategy` through `DesiredCapabilities` Class as follows:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars"); 
    DesiredCapabilities c1 = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    c1.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    c1.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "none");
    WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver(c1);
    Navigation navigate = driver1.navigate();
    navigate.to("https://gmail.com");
```

### Disclaimer:

Using this capability you cannot be sure if the HTML DOM have completely loaded or not for you to continue working with the WebElements present on that Webpage.

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you dev. I tried you solution. In that case, on a line in my code: Set<String> handles = m_chromeWebdriver.getWindowHandles(); I get set size of 1 although I have 2 opened chrome windows. Can you understand why? It doesn;t happen on my original code. Thanks.

Comment: @dushkin Great !!! Can you Accept the Answer as a Solution to your Question to Close this discussion? You are welcome to raise another Question on `getWindowHandles` for us to help you out. Thanks

Comment: it is quite a problem given the problem I described on last comment, because I cannot check the solution... I have a chrome window and a popup windows popped out of it which I need to access, but cannot because of the problem.